# covariance in 2 dimensional field

Tags: correlation

I want to know is the covariance equation which is shown below is how valid when we are in 2-dimensional fields (not 2-dimensional data)?

$$Cov(x,y)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-y)}{N-1}$$

for instance, suppose we want to find COV(x,y) given two elements of x and y:

```
x_samples={ [[1,2],[3,4]] , [[5,6],[7,8]] }

y_samples={ [[9,10],[11,12]] , [[13,14],[15,16]] }
```

can I use the above equation for this space?
 This way unlike scaler space $Cov(x,y)$ is not equal to $Cov(y,x)$. is it true?

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by "2-dimensional fields."  Your bracket notation is not standard mathematical notation.

Comment: suppose u have scaler numbers of x samples, {1,2}, and y samples, {3,4}, then you can compute COV(x,y) easily, but what if we have 2dimentional matrix instead of each sample ( 1, 2, 3, 4)? like the above samples I mentioned as an example. can we use same COV formula?

Comment: Could you explain what this two-dimensional matrix represents?

Comment: u can imagine that we have to class of images; x and y, and we have for each class 2 sample images, and each sample is a 2*2 matrix, like above, so I want to find covariance of these two classes.